# IsGroupingEnabled="true" makes listview empty

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, expandablelistview

I have an existing project with a listview and I would like to add an expandable listview so I've followed this guide: https://github.com/my-jabin/ExpandableListView-Xamarin

This is my listview:

```
 <ListView
            IsGroupingEnabled="true"
            Margin="0"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSourceListView}"
            Grid.Row="2"
            IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
            IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
            HasUnevenRows="false"
            RefreshCommand="{Binding Reload}"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Header="{Binding ShowHeaderObject}"
            Footer="{Binding FooterObject}"
            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource DarkPrimaryColor}"
            SeparatorVisibility="Default"
            CachingStrategy="RecycleElementAndDataTemplate"
            SeparatorColor="{StaticResource LightSeparator}"
            RowHeight="140"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewTemplate}">
            <ListView.FooterTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label
                            Text="{Binding .}"
                            Margin="20"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            TextColor="White" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.FooterTemplate>
            <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label
                            Text="{Binding .}"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            TextColor="White" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
             <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>                   
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image 
                            Source="{Binding Flag}"
                            BorderColor="White"
                            BorderThickness="2"
                            HeightRequest="75"
                            WidthRequest="65">
                        </Image>
                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="1">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="#005569" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Code}" FontSize="Micro" TextColor="#005569" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>                        
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <RelativeLayout Padding="16,8,8,16" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#E2F5F9">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                           FontSize="Large"
                           RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.1}"
                           RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0, Constant=6}"  />
                        <RelativeLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference currentPage}, Path=BindingContext.HeaderClickCommand}"  NumberOfTapsRequired="1" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                        </RelativeLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    </RelativeLayout>
              </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

The new code that I added to the listview in order to implement expandable listview was this (also added IsGroupingEnabled="true"):

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>                   
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <controls:CircleImage 
                            Source="{Binding Flag}"
                            BorderColor="White"
                            BorderThickness="2"
                            HeightRequest="75"
                            WidthRequest="65">
                        </controls:CircleImage>
                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="1">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="#005569" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Code}" FontSize="Micro" TextColor="#005569" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>                        
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <RelativeLayout Padding="16,8,8,16" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                           FontSize="Large"
                           RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.1}"
                           RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0, Constant=6}"  />
                        <Image x:Name="StateImage" PropertyChanged="StateImage_PropertyChanged"
                           Source="{Binding StateIcon}" 
                           RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.8}"/>
                        <RelativeLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference currentPage}, Path=BindingContext.HeaderClickCommand}"  NumberOfTapsRequired="1" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                        </RelativeLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
```

Above the listview, I have grids to bind to the listview:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate
            x:Key="ListViewTemplate">
```

I'm thinking the error I'm making is in the listview and I'm not super experienced when it comes to XAML. The listview is totally blank with this XAML. I really appreciate all the help I can get.

UPDATE:

When I remove the new code that I added from the expandable listview guide but keep the  IsGroupingEnabled="true" the listview shows which viewmodel the listview in binded to. How can I make the code look the same with IsGroupingEnabled="true"?